# CSS active division background color change

Tags: html, css, hover

I am still learning, so please bear with me.

Please check this page first : [My site](http://www.solarkingindia.com/product/history-of-cse/)

Scroll a bit and check the sidebar with name NAVIGATE.
As you can see, I have manually added few sub-menus there and I have added background color change on hover over each division.
Now I want to make it like when I am on the History of CSE page, the NAVIGATE column's sub-option should show the active division or active link.

Means that I want the :active property there. The active page's division will show a different background color, say green.

I tried to search a lot, but didn't get the idea.

Thank you very much!

PS : What I tried to do is this, I am a total newbie, so not sure what to do :

```
div.sbproduct:hover{
    background-color: #F5AC2B;
}

div.sbproduct a:active{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.sbproduct:hover a{
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: `:active` is CSS's equivalent of `onmousedown`, so when you stop clicking it the background color will change back to the default

Comment: Oh. So can there be any other option like if there is an active tab, its color will be different than others? Like current division or selected division?

Comment: You'll have to use javascript to do so

Answer (score 1):

I think this may helps you .....use a toggle() to change the active division background color

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4GSR/4/)

```
// It changes the active  division background color
$( ".sbproduct" ).toggle(
function() {
 $( this ).addClass( "change" );
 },
 function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "change" );
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("a").click(function(){
        //alert('hi');
          $("a").removeClass()
            $(this).addClass("over")


        }) ;        

    });
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dineshk/X4GSR/6/